# Как изменить часовой пояс в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Время на десктопе правильное:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так показывает верное время, а именно 10-47 (файл в корне сайта на вордпрессе локально):

```
<?php
//require_once( 'wp-load.php' );
echo date("H-i");
```

При подключении апи вордпресса:

```
<?php
require_once( 'wp-load.php' );
echo date("H-i");
```

время отображается на три часа меньше: 7-47

Где можно исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В консоли сайта Настройки - Общие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После подключения ядра, надо пользоваться встроенной функцией WordPress `current_time()`. Второй параметр этой функции позволяет получить время GMT или локальное. Вот пример, который иллюстрирует это:

```
<?php
echo 'Время php: ' . date( 'H-i' ) . '<br>';
require_once '../wp-load.php';
echo 'Время php после подключения WP: ' . date( 'H-i' ) . '<br>';
echo 'Время WP GMT: ' . current_time( 'H-i', 1 ) . '<br>';
echo 'Время WP local: ' . current_time( 'H-i', 0 ) . '<br>';
```

Результат:

```
Время php: 12-24
Время php после подключения WP: 09-24
Время WP GMT: 09-24
Время WP local: 12-24
```

Проверить можно на странице тестового сайта http://test.kagg.eu/so/891232.php

Comment: поставил Киев, но ничего не поменялось

Comment: У вас должно быть текущее время правильное. Вот как у меня на картинке.

Comment: @ KAGG Design добавил скрины

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: И что вас сподвигло на то, чтобы отменить принятие этого ответа, как правильного?

Comment: Я его отметил, как решение, но система почему-то отклонила, пока типа вы не отредактируете его.

Comment: Надо же... Бывают странности. Спасибо за пояснение.

Comment: супер, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, WordPress меняет временную зону. Попробуйте это отследить:

```
date_default_timezone_get( void )
```

Чтобы задать нужный часовой пояс:

```
date_default_timezone_set( string $timezone_identifier )
```